# Python поиск по элементам

Tags: python, selenium, requests, bs4, scrapy

Почему выдает один элемент, если есть цикл ? И как получить текст по всем элементам ?

```
import requests_html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import xlsxwriter
import re
from parsel import selector
from lxml import html
import time
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

headers = {
'user-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/95.0.0.0 (Edition Yx 02)'

}
url = 'https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--smartfony/26893750/list?was_redir=1&rt=12&rs=eJwzEg1gnMUocLHxwp4LGy42XGy62HJh34W9AHqDDLY%2C&suggest=1&suggest_type=search&suggest_text=%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B&hid=91491&allowCollapsing=1&local-offers-first=0'

page = requests.get('https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--smartfony/26893750/list?hid=91491&suggest=1&suggest_text=Смартфоны&suggest_type=search&was_redir=1&rs=eJwzEg1gnMUocLHxwp4LGy42XGy62HJh34W9AHqDDLY,&rt=12&cpa=1')

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("argument")

options.binary_location = 'C:\Chrone\chrome.exe'

service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(version='102.0.5005.61').install())

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)

browser.get(url)  # Открываем страницу

browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

models = soup.find_all('div', class_='_1GfBD')
models_1 = soup.find_all('span', class_='_1E10J._2o124._1zh3_')
prices = soup.find_all('div', class_='_1He5n _1cQ6F')
goods = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, '_3KhA2 _1Txgh')
span = soup.find_all('span', class_='price-value')
span_s = soup.find_all('h3', class_='_1He5n _36SPc _2kgEE _1KE2k _1cQ6F')

product_name1 = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,'/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]')
print(product_name1)


for i in product_name1:
    product_name2 = i.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_1E10J._2o124._1zh3_")
    print(product_name2)
```

Comment: Перед оператором цикла добавьте оператор печати *print(f"Длина списка: {len(product_name1)}")* и проверьте результат.

Comment: Sergey, я проверил, это проверка того, сколько элементов найдено ? Я понимаю, что один. Меня напрягает этот динамический сайт. Прочитал, что XPath может исправить ситуацию, не помогает. То он выдает полный список товара на странице, то один.

Comment: "Я понимаю, что один"  - ну а что же Вы тогда хотите ?!

Comment: "XPath может исправить ситуацию"  - нет, XPath тут абсолютно не причём. Здесь может помочь только Selenium.  Но это очень большая тема и распространяться я не буду.  Смысл просто: многие сайты, которые могут выдавать очень длинные таблицы, приспособлены выдавать эти таблицы по частям.  То есть при открытии странички выдаётся верхушка. Пользователь нажал PgDn, выдаётся следующий кусок. Это довольно сложный механизм. Selenium тут может помочь, так как он "прикидывается"  настоящим пользователем и с его помощь. можно организовать перелистывание.

Ещё раз - это всё не просто.